# How Magento webinar work?

Tags: discussion, support, magento

My question is about to magento webinar.

How Magento webinar work?
How to join Magento webinar?

How to get updates about magento webinar?
Where can i view old Magento webinar?

Comment: Hello there any of you has attended any webinar